Execute function when I create script that inherits from a certain class
I have an auto-generated database script that contains a lot of arrays of classes that derive from DatabaseTable.
At the moment I have only have a MenuItem function that executes the generation, but I would like to automatize that in some way.
I'm considering 2 options in which I could call the MenuItem function:

Whenever I create a script that inherits from DatabaseTable
Whenever I create a script in the folder where all the DatabaseTables are

The second one is harder because new scripts inherit from MonoBehaviour and this could break the generator function.
Any ideas on how I can automatize this?

You could make use of Unity's TypeCache.GetTypesDerivedFrom and e.g. process them in a InitializeOnLoadMethod

If the class does not depend on monobehavior, you have a constructor, the base class constructor will fire, so, for example, you can have classes self register (I did this for an app once to allow people to easily add different email parsing rules which couldnt just be a bit of regex as it had to extract various information) works very well

@BugFinder that is only if the class is instantiated on runtime .. as I understood this is more an editor compile time related question to generate something based on classes derived from a certain type

I think we're missing some crucial infomation here. Specifically on what basis that automatic generation works on. Is it based on some kind of data that exists inside the project? Or does it draw the information from an external database? Unity's AssetPostProcessor can react to various events related to changes to the AssetDatabase. Though should the process be started just when a class is created? What happens when that script is not finished yet? How often do you add such classes? Is it really worth to make this process automatic?

@Bunny83 it is not automated, this is the whole point of the question. I want to make it automatic by making the compiler understand that everytime I add a script that derives from DatabaseTable, it should regenerate the Database (by calling an existing function, say Gen()).
